Prove an operator commutes with an compact normal operator on complex Hilbert space
T is a compact normal operator on a complex Hilbert space H, A and B are linear operators on H. If A commutes with T and B commutes with A, does B commutes with T ? This is a claim in GTM96 (page 57, Theorem 7.12, second edition), but I can't prove it's true.

That's not true as stated. Let $T$ and $B$ be non-commuting normal $2\times 2$ matrices, for example
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\,B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
and $A$ the identity matrix. Then $A$ commutes with $T$ and $B$, yet $T$ and $B$ do not commute.
But this is also not what is claimed in Conway's book. Rather, $B$ is a (bounded linear) operator that commutes with all operators that commute with $T$. Since $T$ itself is an operator that commutes with $T$, the operator $B$ commutes (by definition) with $T$.

Btw, the result itself (Theorem 7.12 from Conway) is unrelated to compactness, it's just easier to prove in this case.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
